# Как узнать id элемента view

Tags: android

Программно добавляю на экран приложения `ViewGroup`, в которой лежат, например, `TextView` и `Button`. Хочу, чтобы по нажатию кнопки текст из `TextView` отображался на экране. Как можно узнать `id` `TextView`? (Либо как ещё можно с ним взаимодействовать)?

//Нажатий на сам TextView не происходит.

Comment: сохранить ссылку на вью при её создании?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предполагаю, что раз вы добавляете программно несколько View (TextView + Button) то полагаю что они как то логически должны быть у вас связаны.

Возможно одним из решений будет добавление Tag для каждой View. Соответственно когда вы кликаете на кнопку, определяете ее Tag и находите связанную TextView. Реализация и прочие тонкости зависят уже от ваших требований

Answer (score 1):

В api 17 появился метод [generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()), он генерирует `id`, который гарантировано не будет конфликтовать с id из xml, его нужно задать через [setId(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)) и дальше использовать.